# ioremap returns abnormal virtual address

Tags: amazon-ec2, arm, arm64, ioremap

I used ioremap to map a register's physical address 0xf4000000, while it returned a very strange and small virtual address 0x0f690dd5, which caused kernel panic when I executed ioread32(virtual address) next. Ioremap can be executed, but why it return such a strange virtual address?

The experiment runs on aws ec2, bare mental, aarch64. I wonder why this is happening and how can I read this register?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct address for the device you are trying to access? What device are you trying to access in the kernel module you're developing? Printing `/proc/iomem` on Ubuntu 19.04 shows no device near that memory address. Detail on your distro environment and kernel version would be helpful.

That returned address looks corrupt, it should be 4k or 64k aligned.  Are you sure your program is also not over-running memory somewhere?

Comment: I want to find the base address of some debug registers, which is saved in the mdrar_el1 register according to the armv8 manual, so before running ioremap I ran and only ran mrs to read mdrar_el1 and it returned 0xf40000000.

The kernel version is 4.15.0-1045-aws and the instance type of ec2 is a1-metal.